# how to specify collection in save method in mongodb/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning mongodb and mongoose i am using a function called save(). This function is working find and saving data to database but how to specify in which collection to save the data.

Comment: You should call the `save()` method on an object of the schema to which the collection refers. Can you post the code where you are calling the `save()` function?

Comment: Please refer to the [getting started guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html#getting-started). What you are looking for is the **model** name which translate to a collection name in the database when saving or querying.
In `const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);` ,  `Kitten` is the name of the collection on the database. Good luck!